# Mapping Haskell type to Postgres database with Persistent

Tags: haskell, persistent

I have a Haskell `Status` type:

```
data Status = FirstViewed | Reviewed | Learned
```

How can I map this data to Persistent Postgres database?

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Vocabulary sql=vocabulary
   word Text
   date UTCTime
   status Status
   deriving Show
|]
```

Comment: You could use the [`derivePersistField`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-template-2.5.2/docs/Database-Persist-TH.html#v:derivePersistField) Template Haskell function to derive the necessary instances for `persistent` to serialize and unserialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Alexis king has said, is correct. You have to do
`derivePersistField "Status"` to create appropriate
`PersistField` instances.

But you also have to derive the Show and Read instances of your
sum type:

```
data Status = FirstViewed | Reviewed | Learned deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

Show and Read instances are needed because `derivePersistField`
uses it to perform appropriate conversion when storing and
retrieving from the database. Also the sum type has to be defined
in a separate file because of stage restriction. You may also
want to look on the chapter of
[peristent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) where this
is well documented.